# parse chunked reply through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any way I can parse a chunked response through AJAX as the chunks are being received?

For example, `server.com/ping` is set up so it sends a new chunk with some javascript in it, something like `ping()`, every 10 seconds which updates a number on the web page visible to the user. Is there a way to parse the individual "chunks" of information through AJAX, basically without reaching XHR state 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

As alternative you might want to check the HTML5 [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/)

Comment: I currently use long polling but it's too cumbersome and I'm looking for a more streamlined approach, and I won't use web sockets for obvious reasons.

Comment: I don't think there are much more alternatives using JS/jQuery. Especially if you don't want to use html5.